# How to make the exe read Modified User Settings at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, settings

I have created a user setting using visual studio 2010 as below

Client.exe.config

```
 <userSettings>
        <Client.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ParamValue" serializeAs="String">
                <value>OFF</value>
            </setting>
        </Client.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
```

However if i modify the value during runtime from "OFF" to "ON", the application still access the old value.  But if i close the app and open again then it reads the updated value.

Is there someway to make the exe read the updated user settings at runtime .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ApplicationSettingsBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a Reload method on it you can use to reload the settings from disk.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
// Properties.Settings.Default.ParamValue will be reloaded from the file on disk.
```

You didn't specify how you were changing the settings, but it's worth noting that if you update 'User' settings through the 'Save' method of the settings instance, Reload will no longer reset the value if the saved value was different to the default. This is because 'User' settings are written to a settings file in the user profile folder and once they're saved you would have to update that version of the file, not the one in the bin folder for your application.

Specifically, 'User' settings that are saved back to disk through the [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.save(v=vs.110).aspx) method are written to the following location.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\<YourAppName>\<MangledName>\<Version>\user.config
```

If you want to reset your settings back to the default value you've defined in your App.config, use the [Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
// Properties.Settings.Default.ParamValue will be reset to the default.
```

Comment: In my case i am giving the user a provision to update the client.exe.config file with the required values at runtime . The button in the screen will call Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() method and get the updated values which is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to read the settings into an object on load. Use that object as you want, updating the values if needed. Then on closing of the application write the values of the object back to the config file.

Comment: Instead of user settings if i use appSettings and add ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings"), then i am able to get updated values at runtime